# Notification page does not come up when notification is clicked

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

I am so ashamed for asking this question because i know better, but right now I am so stuck! I wrote my code to call an activity when a notification is clicked. However, overtime i click the notification, the activity does not start, instead the notification just goes away. I have a Receiver.java which extends BroadcastReceiver and then calls the Alarm Service which contains the notification builder I set up. Here is the notification builder I have used:

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(Alarm.this,NotificationPage.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(Alarm.this,1,intent1,0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(Alarm.this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentTitle(from);
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setSound(sound);
    builder.build();
    nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notify=builder.getNotification();
    notify.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(0, notify);
```

everything but the notification page popping up, works. I tested it on a device and the app did not crash so I know there is no error.
Please help!

Frustrated coder atm

Answer (score 1):

```
public void notifyIncomingRequest(Context context,String message)
{
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    intent.putExtra("notification", true);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    intent.setClass(context, YOURCLASS.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(true);

    boolean notification = true;
    boolean notification_vibration = false;
    boolean notification_sound = true;



    String title = "YOURTITLE";
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    String msg=message;
    mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title));


    if(notification){

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        Notification notify = mBuilder.build();

        if(notification_vibration)
            notify.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        if(notification_sound)
            notify.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("number", 13)), notify);
    }
}
```

YOURCLASS.class is the Activity that you want to be displayed after clicking notification, try to call this function with appropriate context and message and you are good to go.

Comment: it comes every minute not every day like i wanted

Comment: @droidnoob its up to your service which asks for notification whether to show notification in every day or every minute, check your service and make sure you are calling notifyIncomingRequest method every day not every minute. (by the way i cant see any information about what you mentioned in your comment as part of your main question)